# Let $f:[0,1]\to(0,1)$ be a surjective function. Prove that $f$ has at least one point of discontinuity.

Tags: functions

> Let $f:[0,1]\to(0,1)$ be a surjective function. Prove that $f$ has at least one point of discontinuity.

---

$f$ is surjective, so all elements in codomain must be mapped to from some element in domain. I'm trying to think of some argument from here, but I'm stuck. Any hints please?

Comment: The basic result is: the image of a compact space under a continuous function is compact. Since $[0,1]$ is compact, and $(0,1)$ is not, there can be no continuous surjection.

Answer (score 2):

The interval $[0,1]$ is compact, so if $f$ had no discontinuities (i.e., if $f$ were continuous), then $f([0,1])$ would have to be compact. But by assumption, $f([0,1]) = (0,1)$, which is not compact, contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

For each $n\in\Bbb N,$ choose $x_n\in[0,1]$ such that $f(x_n)=\frac1n.$ As a bounded sequence, [$(x_n)$ admits a convergent subsequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bolzano%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) $x_{n_k}\to x,$ and $x\in[0,1]$ (since $0\le x_{n_k}\le1\;(\forall k)$). This $x$ is a point of discontinuity of $f,$ otherwise we would have
$$0=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac1{n_k}=\lim_{k\to\infty}f(x_{n_k})=f(x)\in\operatorname{im}f=(0,1),$$contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ where continuous the image of $f$ would be compact(closed and bounded) , since $[0, 1]$ is a compact interval, but the image of $f$ is $(0, 1) $, since $f$ is surjective. $(0, 1) $ is open so que have a contradiction.

Comment: There is an argument missing to explain why $(0,1)$ is not compact. Saying that it is open (in $\Bbb R$ I presume) is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know about compactness, you need the lemma:

> If $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ is continuous then there exists an $x_0\in [0,1]$ such that $f(x_0)=\sup_{x\in [0,1]} f(x).$

It follows immediately from this lemma.

Comment: What does $f(x_0)=\sup_{x\in [0,1]} f(x)$ mean?

Comment: @Ellie_Wong It means that $f$ attains its maximum value at some point $x_0$ in the interval.

Comment: Isn't that the Extreme Value theorem? Also how does this lemma solve the problem?

Comment: I suppose it is. I couldn't recall a name for the theorem. @Ellie_Wong